# How can Maven download all dependencies of a SVN subproject without downloading the whole Trunk?

Tags: svn, maven

I am downloading a maven project by `SVN`. This project is part of a much bigger one.

When I do a `mvn install` of that POM I get errors for not having the POM parents.

How can I get maven to download all dependencies needed by my POM without having to download the whole trunk of the project?

**EDIT**
For instance, I'd like to download, compile and run [this](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tuscany/sca-java-1.x/trunk/samples/zipcode-jaxws/) example:

Answer (score 0):

During build phase Maven knows nothing about version control system. So, someone will have to install all required dependencies (including all parent poms) into a local/team Maven repository.

If there is no such repository available then you will have to checkout the whole thing and to `mvn install` for the whole thing yourself. After that you can remove it and work with one module (assuming the rest of the project won't change).

Comment: Yes, I want Maven to do that. But can't Maven do it with the svn URL tracking the POM parents and downloading only my effective POM?

Comment: @eskalera No it cannot. Subversion is only a source repository while maven uses binary repositories like Artifactory and others.

Comment: Combined they could download the pom parent and the repositories. Doesnt the Maven SCM plugin do something like that?

Comment: @maba that is what I mean. SVN could point to where the poms are and maven would download the efecctive pom. I can't believe nothing like this exists.

Comment: I added clarification about version control system to the answer. As @maba pointed out, source repositories and artifact repositories Maven works with are different things. It would be a bad idea to start fetching random sources from source repositories (basically it will break build reproducibility).

Answer (score 0):

@eskalera, SCM plugin just gives the repo from where the source can be downloaded. In our case Trunk. Once the download is done, it proceeds to he build. SCM plugin wont have any idea of the dependencies needed by the pom during the build. It can only check out the targeted repo.

The only way is to download the entire trunk which will resolve all your dependency issues and as maba suggested, delete the source which is not likely to change.